# prevent react from logging specific errors

Tags: reactjs, api, error-handling

Working on a login system in react, if the email/user is invalid, the api return 401 status code, as expected.

I added a span that notify the user with the problem, but react still log this "scary" errors in the console, how can I prevent the log of error with specific "reasons" / status codes?

Comment: react is not logging, it's in fact your web browser, so you can do nothing about it.

Comment: which library are you using for loggin?

Comment: @Eduard didn't imported any library

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's what you are looking for, but the "ESLint" NPM package can be used to ignore warnings in react files and it can be used to ignore just one line as well.

To ignore all warnings in the file use:

> /* eslint-disable */

On the top of the file and it won't console the warnings from this file anymore, I, unfortunately, don't know more about it but here is the [documentation to get started](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started).